# How to redirect Teamcity to read from a file instead of standard output?

Tags: file, redirect, teamcity, stdout, tap

I am trying to add a Matlab unit test suite to team city. The matlab tests use the TAPPlugin, which is outputting the TAP output to a file. There is too much logging to the standard output to be able to use that successfully.

I've added the TAP plugin to Teamcity, which works when the standard output is TAP. Now, how do I get TeamCity to read from the file instead of the standard output so the tests results are updated in Teamcity on the fly?

I'm thinking I could pipe the std out to a log file, then just redirect the output of the file? Is there a better way, using Teamcity's Service Messages perhaps?

Comment: How do you get the TAP to output to standard out so you can see it in the build log? I'm doing runner = TestRunner.withTextOutput;, but nothing goes to standard out. how do you run the tests? just use a command line runner?

Answer (score 0):

What I do for on my side, is writing both in a file and in TeamCity output. You can do on the fly, or at the end of writing file, dump it on stdout.

Answer (score 0):

A couple options I see solving this on the MATLAB side (I may not be able to speak to TeamCity's apis as well):

1. Redirect MATLAB's TAPPlugin to some file and then as a subsequent build step print that file to stdout. Perhaps this way you would at least be able to keep the MATLAB TAP Stream together in one contiguous chunk of the TeamCity log.
2. Use [MATLAB's XML plugin](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.unittest.plugins.xmlplugin-class.html) to produce JUnit style output. Then you create the appropriate xml file from your MATLAB run and then add a build feature (not a build step, its a different page in your build configuration) in TeamCity to process the JUnit style XML. The build feature you want is XML report processing.

There are pros/cons to consider between JUnit and the TAP format, but if your verbose TeamCity log is causing problems with your TAP output the JUnit support in TeamCity is independent from the build log and that may be a big plus for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I dit it, and it works just fine:

my MATLAB test file (runTestSuiteTeamCity.m):

```
close all;
clear all; %#ok

import matlab.unittest.TestRunner
import matlab.unittest.TestSuite.*
import matlab.unittest.plugins.TAPPlugin
import matlab.unittest.plugins.ToFile

filename = 'TapDump.tap';

if exist(filename, 'file')
    delete(filename);
end

plugin = TAPPlugin.producingOriginalFormat(ToFile(filename));

suite = matlab.unittest.TestSuite.fromPackage('Test');
runner = TestRunner.withTextOutput;
runner.addPlugin(plugin);
results = runner.run(suite);
disp(results);
disp(fileread(filename))

exit;
```

On TeamCity, I am using a Build Step with Command Line and the following Custom Script:

```
set mllogfile="c:\temp\test_log.txt"
matlab -wait -r "runTestSuiteTeamCity" -logfile %%mllogfile%%
set mlerror=%%errorlevel%%
type %%mllogfile%%
exit %%mlerror%%
```